# How to get MAX ID while grouping on specific column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table structure and sample data. In this table there is sale order's iterations. At first Mouse was requested for 15 `Qty`. Later on buyer decides to update the `Qty` and make it 25 and then again later he realizes he only needs 20. So I want to get the most latest row for specific Item from sale order.

```
CREATE TABLE SaleOrder
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Item VARCHAR(25),
Qty INT
)

INSERT INTO SaleOrder VALUES (1, 'Mouse', 15);
INSERT INTO SaleOrder VALUES (2, 'Key Board', 10);
INSERT INTO SaleOrder VALUES (3, 'Printer', 3);
INSERT INTO SaleOrder VALUES (4, 'Mouse', 25);
INSERT INTO SaleOrder VALUES (5, 'Mouse', 20);
```

Here is the query I have wrote.

```
SELECT ID, Item, Qty
FROM SaleOrder M
WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM SaleOrder S WHERE S.ID = M.ID GROUP BY Item)
```

The expected out put should contain 3 rows like this.

```
ID  Item       Qty
1   Mouse      15
2   Key Board  10
3   Printer    3
4   Mouse      25
5   Mouse      20
```

Is there something I am missing here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to get max one by each `Item`

```
SELECT ID,Item,Qty
FROM (
   SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY ID DESC) rn
   FROM SaleOrder
) t1
where rn = 1
```

another simple way we can try to use `TOP 1 WITH TIES` without a subquery.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ID,Item,Qty
FROM SaleOrder 
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY ID DESC)
```

[SQLfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c1859a009df0179e4b2566cf3d97d993)

Answer (score 3):

You May Use Either of the following Methods :

Using `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY Id DESC),
        *
        FROM SaleOrder
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM CTE
        WHERE RN = 1
```

Using Sub Query

```
SELECT
    *
    FROM SaleOrder SO
        WHERE ID = (
            SELECT MAX(ID) FROM SaleOrder WHERE Item = SO.Item
        )-- You Don't Need the Group By Here
```

Result

```
ID          Item                      Qty
----------- ------------------------- -----------
3           Printer                   3
5           Mouse                     20
2           Key Board                 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following query using `MAX`.

```
SELECT SaleOrder.* FROM (
SELECT MAX(Id) as Id, Item FROM SaleOrder Group By Item
)a INNER JOIN SaleOrder ON a.Id = SaleOrder.Id
```

OR you can also use the following

```
SELECT *
FROM SaleOrder D
WHERE Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM SaleOrder WHERE Item = D.Item)
```

The output in both case is as shown below

```
ID  Item        Qty
--------------------
3   Printer      3
5   Mouse       20
2   Key Board   10
```

You can see the demo here- [**Group By Max Demo**](https://rextester.com/VWT90252)